# Switch to Front Camera in iPhone 4 while running ARToolKit for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, augmented-reality, artoolkit

The documentation of ARToolKit tells that --

> Users can now choose between rear
>   (main) and front cameras, on devices
>   which have more than one camera, and
>   additionally, can request different
>   resolution image data from the
>   cameras. Configuration of these
>   options is performed by use of named
>   parameters to the arVideoOpen()
>   function (in the -start method of the
>   ARViewController class). See
>   http://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/Configuring_video_capture_in_ARToolKit_Professional#AR_VIDEO_DEVICE_IPHONE
>   for allowable options.

But inside the `arVideoOpen()` function I can't find the variable where I can set the front camera on condition that the user is using iPhone or iPod 4.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options for camera control are specified via a video configuration string, which is then passed to arVideoOpen() call. E.g. to choose the front camera:

```
arVideoOpen("-position=front");
```

You can combine options by separating with a space, e.g. to change to the 480p preset, and use the rear camera.

```
arVideoOpen("-preset=480p -position=rear");
```